# Portfolios from Sorts

Tags: optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance, expected-return

Some time ago Almgren and Chriss proposed a method for portfolio optimization based on sorting criteria such as $r_1 > r_2 >... > r_N$ instead of explicit expected returns: see 
[portfolios from sorts](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=720041) and [optimal portfolios from ordering information](https://corp.bankofamerica.com/publicpdf/equities/Optimal_Portfolios.pdf).

The 'portfolio of sorts' approach uses the centroid of the sort instead of returns, but otherwise has the same structure as a mean variance optimization, i.e. a linear program with quadratic constraints.

Is this approach used in practice, and if so, can anybody share their experience with it?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The approach is very interesting. (PS - I fixed a bad link to the second paper.)

Answer (score 1):

A friend constructed an equal weight portfolio for a client that was constrained to a certain number of holdings. I don't mean less than 20 (less than or equal constraints are more common) but =20 holdings. He chose an ordinality based (sort) approach and he liked a paper, but I don't remember which one. Until then I hadn't thought about using the approach nor had I thought a client's policy would stipulate an equal weight portfolio.

There you have one case I know where the approach was used in practice. I don't know of any other cases, but that means almost nothing.

Comment: This is not the *Portfolio from Sorts* method proposed by Almgren and Chriss, but an optimization with a cardinality constraint.